# I want to normalize my data values between range of 0 and 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data values which are values of a vector and are stored in a List. I want those data values to be in range of (0,1) as I have to apply Inverse CDF on these values. The values are simple in a list

Suppose following are the values

```
val listOfValues = List(42.0,7.0,57.0,4.0)
```

I have seen some other solution but that involves complex data. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can use normalizer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#normalizer

Comment: @chlebek My column in dataframe is of type double and it gives me this error **java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector** how do I change my column according to this?

Comment: Use https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#vectorassembler first and then

Answer (score 1):

Use [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#vectorassembler) to convert Double -> Vector[Double] and then use MinMaxScaler

### [MinMaxScaler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#minmaxscaler)

MinMaxScaler transforms a dataset of Vector rows, rescaling each feature to a specific range (often [0, 1]). It takes parameters:

min: 0.0 by default. Lower bound after transformation, shared by all features.
max: 1.0 by default. Upper bound after transformation, shared by all features.